# Certain Email reports not appearing in Service Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, servicecloud, marketing-cloud-connect, content-builder

I have a DE in Shared to which i send emails via Content Builder.

I get the email reports in Service Cloud, however it seems like there are some emails missing in the reports.
I saw that it could be due to the SubscriberKey length ( should be 18 ), which is respected in my case. I've also seen that it could be due to the DE location (should be a SFDE) but shouldn't that imply that all my emails would not be showing and not just some ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: only guided sends with the DE in SFDE and journey builder sends are sent back to SFDC as IER